# Not able to connect to AWS RDS from Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

My EC2 instance has a security group (lets call it `AccessFromEverywhere` with essentially allows inbound HTTP, HTTPS and SSH traffic from all IPs. I then created another security group for the AWS RDS that has port 3306 accessible from `AccessFromEverywhere`. Let's call this security group `AWS-RDS`.

I've then setup an RDS MySQL instance and allowed it access from `AWS-RDS`. When I try and install a fresh copy of Wordpress on this EC2 instance I get the following error:

```
Can’t select database
We were able to connect to the database server (which means your username and password is okay) but not able to select the [db name] database.

Are you sure it exists?
Does the user root have permission to use the syndb database?
On some systems the name of your database is prefixed with your username, so it would be like username_[db name]. Could that be the problem?
If you don’t know how to set up a database you should contact your host. If all else fails you may find help at the WordPress Support Forums.
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: allowed it access from AWS-RDS, what does that mean? is that mean you pick a security group AWS-RDS for RDS?

Comment: Yes. It means that in the field where I can state IPs, I've added AWS-RDS since that field also accepts security group values.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I needed to add a database name in the RDS config. This initial setup does not auto populate that field. The initial configuration creates a database instance but not an actual database.